# Server returns blank page and 200 OK

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, varnish

our server on certain POST requests is returning a blank page with status code 200.

There is no PHP error. Problem reamains even if I manualy clear $_POST array.

How you got any ideas?

Configutation:
nginx
symfony 2.3.20
PHP 5.4.33-1~dotdeb.1
W also have varnish but problem remains after varnish shutdown.

Error reporting in on with option E_ALL

Comment: php_value error_reporting on or off?

Comment: What's the issue then? I mean 200 means OK ;) Jokes aside, you should probably share **which POST parameters** make this behavior appear and maybe share the relevant part of code.

Comment: error reporting is on with E_ALL option. I think this is not problem with $_POST because it remains even when I clear it

Comment: Maybe you have an `exit;`or `die;`somewhere in your code

Comment: @Mario I ve checked it, no exits or die function

Comment: Why did you flag this with a Symfony 2 tag?  In Symfony 2 you would not be accessing $_POST directly.

Comment: I know that $_POST is not accessed directly but among other things i was modifing it in app.php file to see if it is request parameters problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question.

Indeed it was a PHP error - memory limit exhousted. It turned out when I binded to php cgi process via strace. Nginx did not return 500 status code. It did not even view fatal errors and log them (despite error_reporting = On with E_ALL).

I don`t know why. I will ask another question about that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in symfony2 it's easy to return like:

```
return new Response(null, 200);
```

wich does exactly what you say it does. Are you sure you are returning content from symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of symfony you are using? The scenario looks more like a php error caused by mismatched function parameter or non existent function call. 
 -Run your application with debug enabled in your app_dev.php.
 - add E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR in ErrorHandler.php handleFatal() funtion where error type is checked. Generally a mismatched function parameter throws a php error of type E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR and is not handled properly on symfony.
  Once this is done run your page again. Hopefully the error will throw up on your page.
Hope this helps